# Why isn't my if statement working?

Tags: c, if-statement, syntax-error, expression

I was working on a calculator that can operate in C. Suddenly, an error popped up saying it was expecting an expression. I wonder why the if statement isn't working. Here is the code that I typed in!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int symbol;
    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;

    printf("+,-,/,*?");
    symbol = scanf("%d", &symbol);

    if (symbol==*)
    {
        printf("Please enter first number.");
        numberOne = scanf("%d", &numberOne);
        printf("%d %d = ?" , numberOne , symbol);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It said that there was an error on the if statement. Please report my error. :D

Comment: Which if statement? I don't see any code...

Comment: How do i know your error

Comment: Did you copy the code or you typed it in the StackOverflow editor? is `symbol==*` exactly that way in your code?

Comment: Please read the documentation for `scanf()` this `numberOne = scanf("%d", &numberOne);` is completely wrong, and it doesn't do what you are thinking, what you think will happen in this case  `numberOne = scanf("%d%d", &numberOne, &numberTwo);`?

Comment: Im not at that part yet.

Answer (score 3):

Where to start? Ok

1. This syntax for `scanf()` is wrong

   ```
   symbol = scanf("%d", &symbol);
   ```

   this doesn't make sense, think of it, if it was

   ```
   symbol = scanf("%d%d", &symbol, anotherSymbol);
   ```

   what do you think the result would be?

   `scanf()` returns the number of parameters that matched the format string, so the return value in this case is `0` which you already know because it's never going into the `if` condition.
2. If you want to read the characeter `'*'` then you are using the wrong format specifier, because `'%d'` is for integers, so when you input `'*'` it returns `0` because the characeter cannot be converted to integer, and hence nothing matched the format string.

   You should use the `"%c"` format specifier, and be careful to skip whitespaces explicitly since this format specifier requires a space in front of the specifier in the format string itself, in order to ignore spaces, so the correct way would be

   ```
   char symbol;
   if (scanf(" %c", &symbol) != 1)
   {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oh no, it's invalid input, cannot continue\n");
        return -1;
   }
   ```
3. The correct way to compare two `char`'s is

   ```
   if (symbol == '*')
   ```

   note the single quotes, your code was giving you the compilation error, because without the quotes it's just the multiplication operator, or the pointer dereference operator so the compiler didn't actually know because there was no expression after the `*`, and since it was expecting one, **the error suddenly popped up**.
4. The same mistake for the second `scanf()`, the corrected code would be

   ```
   if (scanf("%d", &numberOne) != 1)
   {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oh no, it's invalid input, cannot continue\n");
        return -1;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As iharob says, your `scanf()` result won't do what you want, but the compiler error was at the `if (symbol==*)` line, where the `*` should be `'*'` for it to compile.